# C# form, how to stop a thread with a button?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, loops, while-loop

I am doing a form application in C#, it's a client that receives string with socket from server, I have a thread which runs an endless loop with inside the receive function. When I click a button I have to stop this thread, I have tried with a boolean variable but it doesn't work because the function get stuck on the receive function and the control on the boolean variable is done before when is still true. How Can I do to stop this thread?

This is the function which is runned by the thread:

```
 public void Prova()
        {                    
                while (true)
                {
                    string str = frmRegister.c.Receive();
                    ... doing things...
                }
        }
```

The thread is started in this way:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            t1 = new Thread(Prova);
            t1.Start();       
        }
```

And I have to stop the thread here:

```
    private void goBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            new Form2().Show();           
            this.Hide();
        }
```

The following is my attempt with the CancellationToken:

```
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

public void Prova(CancellationToken token)
       {         
           while(!token.IsCancellationRequested){           
               while (true)
               {
                   string str = frmRegister.c.Receive();
                   ... doing things...
               }
            }
       }

public Form1()
       {
         InitializeComponent();
         tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
         var task = Task.Run(() => Prova(tokenSource.Token));       
       }

private void goBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {      
           tokenSource.Cancel();
           new Form2().Show();           
           this.Hide();
       }
```

Comment: This is slightly beyond me to answer, someone else will be able to sort you out, but I believe if you look up 'CancellationToken', you'll probably be able to find a nice example that should plug into your scenario. That's where I'd start looking.

Comment: I have tried something with CancellationToken but it doesn't work, maybe I used it in a wrong way. Can you suggest how Can I use it? A lot of people suggest to not use Abort()

Comment: I have tried something with CancellationToken but it doesn't work -> post that code.

Comment: @Kevin - Never ever ever stop a thread with `.Abort()`. It can corrupt the run-time and leave the rest of the threads in an unknown state. The only exception is when you are trying to crash out of your app.

Comment: @Carletto - Never do `new Form2().Show();`. You should always retain a reference to every form (as they are `IDisposable`) so that you can ensure that it is closed down properly. You need to release any handles to the form.

Comment: @Carletto - You have a nested `while (true)` inside your `while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)` - that completely negates the checking of the token except for the first run. Don't do that. You need to check the token within each and every loop.

Comment: @Carletto - Also, you are running on a none UI thread inside the task so you really cannot access any UI element at all. Calling `frmRegister.c.Receive()` is likely to be a bad idea.

Comment: for the cancellation token case, you are using two nested endless while loop, and you will never be able to get out of `while (true)` and receive the cancel signal.

Comment: So, I try to move the check of the token inside the `while(true)` or I delete the `while(true)`?

Comment: @Carletto - It seems like removing the `while (true)` is the answer, but you haven't shown us the `... doing things...` code so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use Thread instead of Task?

In your case

```
Thread th;
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

public void Prova(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{                    
        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            string str = frmRegister.c.Receive();
            ... doing things...
        }
}

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        th = new Thread(() => { Prova(cts.Token);  });
        th.Start();;       
}

private void goBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

With task

```
    Task th;
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public void Prova(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ...process
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        th = Task.Run(() => { Prova(cts.Token); }, cts.Token);
        th.Start(); ;
    }

    private void goBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
```

Comment: Never ever ever stop a thread with `.Abort()`. It can corrupt the run-time and leave the rest of the threads in an unknown state. The only exception is when you are trying to crash out of your app.

Comment: And never do `new Form2().Show(); `. You should always retain a reference to every form (as they are `IDisposable`) so that you can ensure that it is closed down properly. You need to release any handles to the form.

Comment: I edited my question with my attempt with CancellationToken

Comment: There's no point doing `new Thread(() => { Prova(cts.Token);  })` when `Task.Run(() => { Prova(cts.Token);  })` is much safer.

Comment: Calling `frmRegister.c.Receive()` inside a non-UI thread is also dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample this should work:

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

public void Prova(CancellationToken token = default)
       {         
           while(!token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                   string str = frmRegister.c.Receive();
                   ... doing things...
               }
            }
       }
```

Or even:

```cs
public void Prova(CancellationToken token = default)
        {                    
                while (true)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    string str = frmRegister.c.Receive();
                    ... doing things...
                }
        }
```

Or:

```cs
public void Prova(CancellationToken token = default)
        {                    
                while (true)
                {
                    if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
                       return;

                    string str = frmRegister.c.Receive();
                    ... doing things...
                }
        }
```

Basically get rid of the double while loop and it works.

Comment: Your `if(token.IsCancellationRequested)` is way better than `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` - throwing sends the coding problem to someone else. Checking if the cancellation is requested means that your code takes responsibility.

Comment: @Enigmativity thats debatable and depends on the situation. In this case i feel like you're right - anyway that's why that solution is on top ;)